# Конвертация большого CSV в XLS

Tags: php, excel, csv

В кастомной CMS есть возможность скачать рабочие данные в формате Excel. Сейчас это происходит через вызов внешнего конвертера CSV → XLS. Никакого стилевого оформления данных нет и не требуется, это просто аналог csv в более понятном для клиентов виде. Хочется заменить внешний конвертер на что-нибудь родное для PHP.

Посоветуйте библиотеку или просто подход, исходя из личного опыта. Подчеркиваю, что данных бывает много! PHPExcel не предлагайте, пожалуйста. Он на больших объемах кушает слишком много памяти.

Comment: Получилось у вас в итоге? Или нет?

Comment: Оно и сейчас работает. Никак не случится такого, что "не получилось". А сбор мнений закончится только через 4 дня. Мне нравятся все ответы, но ни один не идеален, так что я не тороплюсь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я бы не стал писать отдельный ответ, но вы отметили что оформление вас не интересует.

Чтож, мне кажется вам надо разбить задачу на 2 части:

1) Генерация данных по кусочкам - каждый кусок должен быть такого размера, чтобы ваш PHP (с вашими ограничениями по памяти, ресурсам процессора и прочим настройкам) мог спокойно обработать его.

2) Собственно запись данных из конкретного кусочка всей информации в файл.

Исходя из такого подхода, вы можете запустить некий цикл/очередь, и по очереди обработать любое нужное вам количество информации (!). А затем собственно сконвертировать в формат Excel.

Вы конечно же можете использовать вышеозвученный CSV формат, а затем конвертировать его в Excel. Однако, я могу предложить лучшую альтернативу - формат XML (XML Spreadsheet 2003) или Open XML. Для использования этого формата вовсе не обязательно использовать ту же библиотеку PHPExcel, вы можете написать и собственный код, так как вас не интересует оформление, и поэтому большая часть функций PHPExcel вам вообще не нужна.

Что вам нужно это вручную создать нужную структуру формата файла в XML, и в цикле выдавать в него значения из кусочков (file append). В итоге, после завершения обработки всех данных вы получите файл в формате .XLSX и ваш клиент спокойно сможет открыть его в Excel.

В результате у вас получится что-то вроде этого:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"> 
        <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
            <Author>Author</Author>
            <LastAuthor>Author</LastAuthor>
            <Created>2015-04-19T21:57:54Z</Created>
            <Version>14.00</Version>
        </DocumentProperties>
        <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
            <AllowPNG/>
        </OfficeDocumentSettings>
        <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
            <WindowHeight>9264</WindowHeight>
            <WindowWidth>20100</WindowWidth>
            <WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX>
            <WindowTopY>24</WindowTopY>
            <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
            <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
        </ExcelWorkbook>
        <Styles>
            <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
                <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
                <Borders/>
                <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
                <Interior/>
                <NumberFormat/>
                <Protection/>
            </Style>
            <Style ss:ID="s62">
                <Borders>
                    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                </Borders>
            </Style>
        </Styles>
        <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
            <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="3" ss:ExpandedRowCount="3" x:FullColumns="1"
            x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="14.4">
            <Column ss:Index="3" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="208.2"/>
                <Row>
                    <Cell/>
                    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Column 1</Data></Cell>
                    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Column 2</Data></Cell>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Row 1</Data></Cell>
                    <Cell/>
                    <Cell/>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Row 2</Data></Cell>
                    <Cell/>
                    <Cell/>
                </Row>
            </Table>
        </Worksheet>
    </Workbook>
```

Собственно, если вы решите пойти таким путём - вы можете поискать в Гугле по запросам "OpenXML generate Excel" и посмотреть как это делается в разных языках (не только через PHP). Учитывая отсутствие оформления - большая часть проблем у вас будет не с генерацией контента, или конвертированием в XML, а в том чтобы создать исходный шаблон и добиться того, чтобы Excel открывал его правильно.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутое объяснение. Посетителям сайта будет полезно ознакомиться. @andreycha вкратце предложил то же самое, но с готовой библиотекой и эссенцией объяснения: *потоково+xlsx*

Comment: У нас разные решения с одинаковым конечным результатом - файлом .XSLX. Дело в том, что вам не нужна библиотека. У вас нет объединенных ячеек, стилей, шрифтов и прочего - поэтому вам будет проще сделать свою собственную структуру файла, в которой этого всего не будет - таким образом вы уходите от любых проблем, которые могут быть вами унаследованы от библиотеки.

Comment: Я не страдаю от синдрома ["фатального недостатка"](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA) и по возможности пользуюсь готовыми решениями. Беру на себя ответственность за правильный выбор. Сам воспользуюсь PHP_XLSXWriter, но ваш ответ, по совокупности признаков, считаю лучшим :) Получите заслуженный приз!

Answer (score 11):

Не совсем техническое решение, но из личного опыта - уберите конвертер и отдавайте клиентам файл с расширением CSV по кнопке "Экспорт в Excel".

Excel выставляет ассоциации с CSV по умолчанию. У файлов показывается экселевский значок - вобщем, для окончательного пользователя файл ничем не отличим от XLS. Особенно если отображение расширений отключено (опять же, по умолчанию).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Лично я бы с Вами согласился, но люди, далекие от IT-индустрии считают иначе. А сайт работает именно для таких людей. При открытии csv файла задаются "лишние вопросы".

Comment: Эксель не задает вопросов при открытии CSV. Даже лучше - он не задает вопросов при открытии скачанного из интернета CSV (а для для скачанного Excel - задает). У меня тоже продукт для очень далеких от IT пользователей, и за пары лет от тысяч людей - ни одной жалобы и ни одного вопроса "чем это открыть".

Comment: Во-первых, таки задает вопросы - про правильную интепретацию разделителей и кодировку. Во-вторых, тема топика не о выборе формата. Хозяин говорит *что* он хочет, мы решаем *как* это сделать.

Comment: Мой эксель 2013 открывает молча, 2010-й тоже открывал без вопросов. Про разделители и кодировку он спрашивает только при импорте данных через Text Import. Вы попробуйте просто файл открыть, даблкликом в проводнике, а не проимпортировать его. Разработчик должен решать проблемы, а не делать то, что ему сказал хозяин (я бы на вашем месте подумал о смене работы)

Comment: Ок, я подумаю )) Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Он не задает вопросы, если разделитель - точка с запятой, экранирование кавычек- двойная кавычка. Если писать файл сразу в таком формате, то пользователь не увидит никакого запроса о формате данных.

Comment: Раделители, которых ждет эесель, зависят от локали. В американской это запятая - comma. Так что нужно аккуратно угадывать локаль пользователя при формировании csv (не уверен, можно ли это сделать в php более-менее автоматически)

Answer (score 5):

1. Читать потоково.
2. Писать потоково: [PHP_XLSXWriter](https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter)

P.S. Но вообще я бы прислушался к совету @PashaPash и не городил велосипед. CSV прекрасно открывается Экселем.

Comment: Посмотрел код — выглядит интересно, кажется он реально позволяет не тратить память, а сбрасывать данные циклически. Спасибо!

Comment: Вот только из-за неоднозначности не могу признать этот ответ решением. Предлагаете одно и тут-же отрекаетесь в пользу другого, что именно будет считаться верным советом? 
Незачет.

Comment: @artoodetoo поясню свое отречение :). Программист должен быть в меру ленивым. Если одинакового результата можно достичь двумя способами, то надо выбирать способ с минимальными затратами. В  вашем случае -- это отказ от конвертации в XLS и выдача CSV, который клиенты будут открывать в Экселе. Если же это по каким-то серьезным причинам не подходит, то тогда вариант один: потоковые чтение и запись с использованием библиотек, которые это поддерживают.